# How to debug gif errors

Tags: go, gif

I follow [guide by Alan Donovan](https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch1/lissajous/main.go) and try to make gif. But in output all the time I got unreadable gif image. I remember, when I was on Windows 8.0, I can remake this example easy, but today on Ubuntu16.04 I dunno where is my error and how to fix it. My code:

```
package main

import (
    "image/color"
    "os"
    "io"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
    "image/gif"
    "image"
    "math"
)

var palette = []color.Color{color.White, color.Black}

const (
    whiteIndex = 0
    blackIndex = 1
)

func main() {
    lissajous(os.Stdout)
}

func lissajous(out io.Writer)  {
    const (
        cycles = 5
        res = 0.001
        size = 100
        nframes = 64
        delay = 8
    )
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    freq := rand.Float64()*3.0
    anim := gif.GIF{LoopCount:nframes}
    phase := 0.0
    for i := 0; i < nframes; i++ {
        rect := image.Rect(0, 0, 2*size+1, 2*size+1)
        img := image.NewPaletted(rect, palette)
        for t:=0.0; t< cycles*2*math.Pi; t+= res {
            x:= math.Sin(t)
            y:= math.Sin(t*freq + phase)
            img.SetColorIndex(size+int(x*size+0.5), size+int(y*size+0.5), blackIndex)
        }
        phase += 0.2
        anim.Delay = append(anim.Delay, delay)
        anim.Image = append(anim.Image, img)
    }
    gif.EncodeAll(out, &anim)
}
```

Just copied from book. Source file placed in '~/go/src/learning/'

Comment: How do you know it's an unreadable gif? How are you testing? What exact error messages are you getting?

Comment: my problem was that I should open it in web browser, and I tryed programs like Mirage... T_T

Comment: Your comment doesn't answer my questions. What exact error message are you getting?

Comment: I thought if program cant open image, so it is broken image. But answer below shown me that image can be open in firefox. And that's all. I just a bit lame i know. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open with the gif file with a gif reader like firefox. For example,

```
$ go run lissajous.go > lissajous.gif && firefox lissajous.gif
```

Comment: wow its magic ! and why I cant open it in programs like Mirage =(